# Advice on serialization for a game

Tags: java, serialization, game-engine

I'm coding a game. I understand that serialization will be useful for saving and multiplayer. I don't see any reason to use serialversionuid if I force update when multiplayer is selected by the client.

For saving, I have a question: does the id affect my ability to convert saved gameplay data to a new updated version of the game? Or is that all logic based, leaving the id as a simple reference to the version of the game at hand?

Thanks to anyone in advance. I would upvote if my rep was higher :P

EDIT: Both answers were very helpful. From them, I gather this about serialization and game programming: having a s-uid will be beneficial, because different versions of different things in the game will need references to their versions to be able to have compatibility or non-compatibility across versions. One "game version id" would not be enough information. Thanks for clarifying guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `serialVersionUid` is intended to be a hash or version that exactly identifies which version of the `Serializable` class, the data was output by.

Unfortunately it mainly acts as an impediment to serialization -- by causing every minor change to break serialization. Any different version will cause an exception to throw.

Recommended practice is to generate or assign a `serialVersionUid` constant in your java source, to avoid unnecessary incompatibility. From the Javadoc:

> To guarantee a consistent serialVersionUID value across different java
>   compiler  implementations, a serializable class must declare an
>   explicit serialVersionUID value.

If you dig into the Java source you may be able to find methods to implement/override, which can give you more control over serialization.

See:

- java.io.ObjectInputStream
- java.io.ObjectOutputStream
- java.io.Externalizable

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that if you don't have a serialVersionUID one is calculated based on the class structure.  In practice it means if you alter the class somewhat (which can include things that don't simply add instance variables, i.e. things that you wouldn't think would matter for serialization/deserialization), your deserialization will fail because the deserialization of your serialized objects will now yield a serialVersionUID that is *different* from the one calculated for the class you're hydrating it into.

The simple answer is just to declare one. If you do that, java will use the declared one and your serialization will not be as sensitive to changes. Note that you can still break it by adding/removing instance variables, but it will be more robust. It also doesn't matter what it is - it doesn't need to match the long generated from the serialversiontool, it's perfectly safe to use 1 or any other long, just as long as you change it if you make breaking changes to the class.

(edit - some helpful person on SO posted [this reference on how the serialVersionUID is calculated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738162/how-serialversionuid-is-calculated))