# What algorithm is used by eclipse to generate verison id in Serializable class?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialversionuid

Suppose here is my class :

```
class B implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5186261241138469827L; // what algo is used to generate this
     ..........
}
```

What algorithm eclipse uses to generate `serialVersionUID = -5186261241138469827L` ?

Comment: Maybe it's using [serialver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/serialver.html)

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738162/how-serialversionuid-is-calculated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eclipse implements the [relevant Java spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) to compute Serialization ID.

In Eclipse, this is implemented by [calculateSerialVersionId](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.0/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/correction/SerialVersionHashOperation.java#SerialVersionHashOperation.calculateSerialVersionId%28org.eclipse.jdt.core.util.IClassFileReader%29) method in [org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.correction.SerialVersionHashOperation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/4.3/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.9.0/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/correction/SerialVersionHashOperation.java#SerialVersionHashOperation) class.

Answer (score 2):

[Java Object Serialization Specification Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100)  ,given that algo

> The hash value is assembled from the first and second 32-bit values of the SHA-1 message digest. If the result of the message digest, the five 32-bit words H0 H1 H2 H3 H4, is in an array of five int values named sha, the hash value would be computed as follows:

```
  long hash = ((sha[0] >>> 24) & 0xFF) |
              ((sha[0] >>> 16) & 0xFF) << 8 |
              ((sha[0] >>> 8) & 0xFF) << 16 |
              ((sha[0] >>> 0) & 0xFF) << 24 |
              ((sha[1] >>> 24) & 0xFF) << 32 |
              ((sha[1] >>> 16) & 0xFF) << 40 |
              ((sha[1] >>> 8) & 0xFF) << 48 |
              ((sha[1] >>> 0) & 0xFF) << 56;
```