# Does serialVersionUID generation in Eclipse use serialver?

Tags: java, eclipse, serialization, serialversionuid

Eclipse IDE allows generation of random `serialVersionUID`.
On the other hand, there is a tool in JDK, [serialver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/serialver.html), which is designed for the purpose.

Any idea if Eclipse actually invokes serialver behind the curtains?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't require you to have a JDK installed (although it works better if you do) so it doesn't use serialver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer for 
[What algorithm is used by eclipse to generate verison id in Serializable class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19088828/what-algorithm-is-used-by-eclipse-to-generate-verison-id-in-serializable-class)

> Eclipse implements the [relevant](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/class.html#4100) Java spec to compute Serialization ID.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. Have a look at [this](https://github.com/azachar/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/blob/master/org.eclipse.jdt.ui/ui/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/text/correction/SerialVersionHashOperation.java) class `calculateSerialVersionId` method.